# Post build event command whose directory is not C:\

Tags: post-build-event

I want to run a command in the post build event of a project, if i do C:\temp\Client.exe it works fine but If my project is in the thumb drive and change the command to G:\temp\Client.exe it looks like it doesnt like the path and exit with code 9009. what command do i need if the exe is in different path than C drive. Thankx

Comment: Please give more detail - it is hard to say what kind of build tool you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's just in visual studio 2010, and just want to specify the command in post build event, so my problem is that my project in in dumb drive and looks like i have to specify additional command to get it to pick the exe from F:\.. looks like i have to change the directory before giving it the exe to run. trying to find the right dos syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From the question and subsequent comment it looks that drive letter keeps changing. It is possible in post-build section check if the file exist before call it.

For debugging you can use something like

```
f:
Dir
```

And view output window after the build.